# What's the difference in "open" between Windows vs. Linux?

Tags: ssh, tcl

In Windows 7, when running a Tcl script that uses `open` to interact with a remote Linux PC via ssh, it's possible to see the prompt of the remote PC.
Example of code:

```
set fh [open "|./plink -ssh $user@$ip -pw $password" w+]

catch {fconfigure $fh -blocking 0 -buffering none -translation binary} output

set i 0
while {1} {
    puts -nonewline stdout "iter $i. "
    set data [read -nonewline $fh]
    puts -nonewline $data
    if {$i > 3} {
        puts $fh "ls -l\r"
    }
    after 1000
    incr i
}
```

Which has the following output (some output of `ls` was trimmed for better readability):

```
C:\test>tclsh openInWindows.tcl
iter 0. iter 1. Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.5.0-45-generic i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

99 packages can be updated.
62 updates are security updates.

Last login: Mon Apr  7 13:17:20 2014 from 1.2.3.4
←]0;root@MyPC: ~root@MyPC:~# iter 2. iter 3. iter 4. iter 5. ls -l
total 1876
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Apr  3 13:34 ←[01;34mDesktop←[0m
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Apr  3 13:34 ←[01;34mDocuments←[0m
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Apr  3 13:34 ←[01;34mDownloads←[0m
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Apr  3 13:34 ←[01;34mMusic←[0m
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Apr  3 13:34 ←[01;34mPictures←[0m
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Apr  3 13:34 ←[01;34mPublic←[0m
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Apr  3 13:34 ←[01;34mTemplates←[0m
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Apr  3 13:34 ←[01;34mVideos←[0m
←]0;root@MyPC: ~root@MyPC:~# ^C
C:\test>
```

But when the same script (with minor modification) is run in Linux, the prompt of the remote PC doesn't appear (though it's still possible to execute command and get the results).

The code for Linux:

```
set fh [open "|sshpass -p $password ssh $user@$ip" w+]

catch {fconfigure $fh -blocking 0 -buffering none -translation binary} output

set i 0
while {1} {
    puts -nonewline stdout "iter $i. "
    set data [read -nonewline $fh]
    puts -nonewline $data
    if {$i > 3} {
        puts $fh "ls -l"
    }
    after 1000
    incr i
}
```

Which has the following output (some output of `ls` was trimmed for better readability):

```
root@MyUbuntu:~# tclsh openInLinux.tcl
iter 0. iter 1. Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.5.0-45-generic i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

99 packages can be updated.
62 updates are security updates.
iter 2. iter 3. iter 4. iter 5. total 1876
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Apr  3 13:34 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Apr  3 13:34 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Apr  3 13:34 Downloads
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Apr  3 13:34 Music
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Apr  3 13:34 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Apr  3 13:34 Public
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Apr  3 13:34 Templates
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Apr  3 13:34 Videos^C
root@MyUbuntu:~#
```

(I had to hit CTRL + C soon, otherwise the `ls` command would've been executed many times)

Why this difference exists between Linux and Windows?
Is it possible to have the prompt of the remote PC to be displayed when this code run under Linux?

Comment: Just checking… are these two scripts connecting to the same remote host? (I think it _might_ be so from your description, but I'm not sure and if not, that could be a significant difference.)

Comment: @DonalFellows: Yes, they connect to the same remote host.

Comment: is it possibly related to the ssh client, not to tcl?

Comment: @msb: I don't know, how would you check that..?